# Simple integral with $e^x$ - how to decompose it?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to calculate this integral?

$$\int \frac{e^{2x}+2}{e^x+1}dx$$

I have tried various substitions such as: $t = e^x, t = e^x + 1, t = e^x +2, t = e^{2x}$
and none seem to work.

According to wolframalpha I can simplify this expression into:

$$\frac{e^{2x}+2}{e^x +1} = e^x + \frac{3}{e^x+1} - 1$$

And then it'd be rather simple. But still no idea how to decompose it like that.

Any tips?

Comment: What goes wrong with $t=e^x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{e^{2x}+2}{e^x +1}&=\frac{(e^{x})^2+2e^x+1-2e^x+1}{e^x +1}\\
&=\frac{(e^x+1)^2-2e^x+1}{e^x +1}\\
&=e^x+1+\frac {-2e^x-2+3}{e^x +1}\\
&=e^x+1-2+\frac {3}{e^x +1}\\
&=e^x + \frac{3}{e^x+1} - 1
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \frac{e^{2x}+2}{e^x+1}dx$$
Applying $u=e^x\implies dx=\frac{du}{u}$ gives the following integral
$$\int \frac{u^2+2}{u+1}\frac{du}{u}=\int \frac{u^2+2}{u(u+1)}du$$
Using [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Example_1) gives
$$\frac{u^2+2}{u(u+1)}=-\frac3{u + 1} + \frac2u + 1$$
Hence the integral becomes
$$\int (-\frac3{u + 1} + \frac2u + 1)du=-3\ln{(u+1)}+2\ln{(u)}+u+C$$
$$=-3\ln{(e^x+1)}+2\ln{(e^x)}+e^x+C$$
$$=-3\ln{(e^x+1)}+e^x+2x+C$$

Answer (score 1):

For the last integral you can substitute$$\int\frac{1}{e^x+1}dx$$ $$t=e^x+1$$ and $$dt=e^xdx=(t-1)dx$$ or $$dx=\frac{1}{t-1}dt$$

Comment: Still, no idea how to get to that point. Wolframalpha simplified that expression for me.

Comment: But i have all written for you!